# Manifold without conjugate points and positive curvature

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I'm looking for an example of a complete riemannian manifold with sectional positive curvature and without conjugate points. I've tried the projective space, but the identfication used to construct it does not take out the conjugated points: instead of it, this identificates them. Does anyone know some simple example?

Comment: What does positive curvature have to do with your question? You have "and positive curvature" in the title, but nothing about it in the body of the question. (You should also specify what kind of curvature, and also whether it is nonnegative, strictly positive, or bounded below by a positive constant).

Comment: @5PM Sorry, I make an edit

Comment: Maybe a two-sheeted hyperboloid? (I haven't checked)

Comment: Paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ would work too, I guess. (I haven't checked either)

Comment: According to this: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211091.pdf (pg 2 and 3), the paraboloid *does* have conjugate points.  (Though, I think for geodesics starting at the vertex there are none.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Thanks for your links! Very interesting. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any example of what you seek.

More specifically, [this paper](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/aabc/v72n2/0016.pdf) has a proof of the following claim:

> Assume $M$ is complete and has no conjugate points.  If there is a point at which the Ricci curvature in all directions is non-negative, then $M$ is flat.  That is, all sectional curvatures are $0$.

The contrapositive gives that there is no $M$ with positive sectional curvature and no conjugate points.

Comment: do you know if the inexistence of positively curved spaces without conjugate point was known before this paper?

Comment: This paper references a result by Liang and Zhan on the bottom of the first page:  If $\gamma$ is a geodesic without conjugate points and the Ricci curvature in the direction of $\gamma$ is non-negative, then it is flat.  That's already enough to get the result about nonexistence of conjugate free positively curved manifolds.  I wasn't able to track down a copy of the Liang-Zhan paper, so I don't know how they do it or who they reference.

Comment: I think the result is not exactly for the Ricci curvature an one point, but to the Ricci curvature calculated along a geodesic definer on all $\mathbb{R}$, but we still have that there is no manifold positively curved and without conjugate points.